# Excel Conditional Formatting Offset Greater than

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I need to create a conditional formatting rule that will apply some color if the cell to the left has a value greater than 500, however it is not accepting my formula:

```
=OFFSET(0,-1) > 500
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

[image: formula]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**
I think you would not be able to use conditional formatting this way with icon sets. I got the following error when I tried:

> You cannot use relative references in
>   conditional formatting criteria for
>   color scales, data bars, and icon
>   sets.

I was, however, able to achieve the same by applying this formula to right column and then applying conditional formatting rule on this column as show in the screen shot.

```
=IF(OFFSET(E10,0,-1)>500,1,IF(OFFSET(E10,0,-1)=500,0,-1))
```

[image]

[image]

The formula should be:

```
=OFFSET(E10,0,-1)>500
```

In Excel, the Offset function returns a reference to a range that is offset a number of rows and columns from another range or cell.

The syntax for the Offset function is:

```
Offset( range, rows, columns, height, width )
```

- range is the starting range from
  which the offset will be applied.
- rows is the number of rows to apply
  as the offset to the range. This can
  be a positive or negative number.
- columns is the number of columns to
  apply as the offset to the range.
  This can be a positive or negative
  number.
- height is the number of rows
  that you want the returned range to
  be.
- width is the number of columns
  that you want the returned range to
  be.

Comment: Tried that and it's giving me a "Please enter a valid formula" error.

Comment: @nmuntz I have updated the answer.

Comment: That worked out great ! Thank you very much!
I would have never guessed that you cant use formulas with icon sets

Answer (score 3):

There is a way of achieving the equivalent of **Offset** in **Conditional formatting** with relative references.

In the cell you want conditionally coloured, select the conditional formatting option *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*. In the formula bar use the following syntax:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()+X,COLUMN()-Y))>Z
```

Here, `X` is the vertical offset, `Y` is the horizontal offset and `Z` is the value against which you are testing.

In the OP's example, it would be:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1))>500
```

You then just need to define the formatting; you can't have the traffic light symbol but you can set the cell's background or font to be a specific colour.

Answer (score 0):

In your case (fixed offset), there is a much simpler way to achieve your goal:
when moving/extending conditional formatting, absolute/relative reference are handled sensibly (even if this is undocumented *afaik*).
For example edit conditional formatting on cell B2, and write in the condition
"=A2>500". Then copy format (or extend) on the others cells you want formatted that way.
That's it.
If you need something more flexible, e.g. getting the actual offset from a second cell, you have to revert to the INDIRECT() solution.